# Add syntax highlighting for [lotusscript]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I know, that I might be a "dinosaur" as coding in IBM Notes / Domino nowadays should mainly consist of XPages, JavaScript, Java, HTML5, etc.

But there are still questions in stackoverflow for the language LotusScript, and I use it a lot. 
This language can be described as a "dialect" of visual basic and uses nearly the same syntax. It would be great, if questions tagged as "lotusscript" could automatically use the prettify- tag lang-vb (I always add it to my own posts as it makes the code better readable).

Comment: "trilobyte" sounds cooler.

Comment: I don't get what you mean...